# IndexRequest is deprecated

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I'm using `RestHighLevelClient`, in the `main` method I use `IndexRequest` (this one is closed off because is deprecated). I use 7.10.1 elasticsearch. When I run the program, I have error message below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.createHttpClient(RestClientBuilder.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.build(RestClientBuilder.java:201)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:291)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(RestHighLevelClient.java:283)
    at com.gihub.simplesteph.kafka.tutorial3.ElasticSearchConsumer.createClient(ElasticSearchConsumer.java:41)
    at com.gihub.simplesteph.kafka.tutorial3.ElasticSearchConsumer.main(ElasticSearchConsumer.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

I need your support to solve my problem, below are code of `ElasticSearchConsumer.java`and `pom.xml`. I tried many recipe but I have the same error.

```
package com.gihub.simplesteph.kafka.tutorial3;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ElasticSearchConsumer {

    public  static RestHighLevelClient createClient(){

        // replace with your own credentials
        String hostname = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxxx";

        //don't do if you run a local ES
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost(hostname, 443, "https"))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpAsyncClientBuilder) {
                        return httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                });
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConsumer.class.getName());
        RestHighLevelClient client = createClient();

        String jsonString = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }";

        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("twitter", "tweets" ).source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);

        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        String id = indexResponse.getIndex();
        logger.info(id);

        //close the client gracefully
        client.close();

    }
}
```

pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kafka-beginners-course</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>kafka-consumer-elasticsearch</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not a deprecation notice, you're just missing [a few dependencies](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-dependencies.html)

Comment: Which dependencies?

Comment: Follow the link?

Comment: I add the six depensencies of the link, I still have the same error message.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` usually means that the dependency was there at compile time, but not at runtime. Can you make sure that when you run your project it has all the necessary deps on the classpath?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I correct the path and there is no error message just a warning message 'Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated... '. The code was supposed to return the Id document but he return 'twitter'.

Comment: Ok, then the initial problem is solved. That one is a new problem for which you should create a new question (to not mix subjects)

Comment: Thank you I create another one!

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` usually means that the dependency was present at compile time, but not at runtime.

You need to make sure that when you run your project it has all [the necessary dependencies on the classpath](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `org.apache.httpcomponents` dependency in the main module if you have multiple modules in your setup, it worked for me.

And while creating `IndexRequest`, don't add topic in the constructor,
use it like:

```java
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(
    "ur_index"
).source(urJsonString, XContentType.JSON);
```